# Good audio playback library for playing .flac and other loss less formats in Swift?

Tags: swift, audio, flac, lossless

I've tried https://github.com/ap4y/OrigamiEngine but I can't get it to play flac files.

here's a sample

```
var url = "/Users/Simun/Downloads/track.flac"
url = url.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
let trackUrl = NSURL(string:"file://localhost/\(url)")
player.playUrl(trackUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of other libraries for playing FLAC in Swift, but https://github.com/ap4y/OrigamiEngine does do the job. The most difficult part for me was simply getting this Objective-C library included in a Swift XCode project using cocoapods (importing the headers and linking). Once that is accomplished, the following code should play a file:

```
let origami = ORGMEngine()
origami.play(URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/user/xyz.flac"))
```

Comment: Hi there!, Can you explain how did you manage to do it? I didn't want to use cocoapods so I exported the .a with its headers. I managed to play mp3 but flac isn't working :( Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded to preview .flac files using two native things:

- AVKit's AVPlayerViewController
- QuickLook